# Syncing Firefox Android downloads in Dropbox

Tags: firefox-for-android, dropbox

I use an Android phone. I use Firefox and Chrome as browsers on it. I want to set the download location for Firefox to a location on Dropbox installed on my phone, such that all my downloads are directly synchronized to a folder which I can even access on my PC.

I am unable to do so. I have tried doing the instructions posted here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1028808

The other option is dropsync. Is there any option which doesnot involve using Dropsync?

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the link worked on my Pixel 2 with Android 9, using a fresh install of Firefox 62.0.2. But it wasn't on my first attempt. It turned out I was too confident when entering the value of `browser.download.dir`.

Let's say I wanted to change the download folder from "Download" to "Music". So I put in the value `/Music`, since I thought I didn't need the help of a file manager to get the path of such a simple directory. But nothing happened. Files were still been downloaded to the "Download" directory.

When I actually used a file explorer (specifically, "Total Commander"), it turned out that the actual path to the "Music" directory was the oh-so-memorable `/storage/emulated/0/Music`. So when I changed `browser.download.dir` to that value, it worked.